# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: "units"'

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

**Inserted keras libraries and packages are below,**

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
```

**Initialize the CNN models**

```
classifier = Sequential()
```

**#1st Step:- Convolution**

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(64,64,3), activation='relu'))
```

**#2nd Step:- Pooling**

```
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2) ))
```

**#3rd Step:- Flattening**

```
classifier.add(Flatten())
```

**#full connection**

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation='relu'))   #Here show the error
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

**#compiling the CNN**

```
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Below the error,**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3df4f496ff43> in <module>()
      1 #full connection
----> 2 classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation='relu'))
      3 classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
      4 
      5 #compiling the CNN

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'
```

**Note:** Need help, so please help me.

Comment: `units` is a required argument when you make a Dense layer.  This is clear in the documentation.  What do you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong parameters, as the error states you probably wanted to write:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation='relu'))   
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother ! it's a great help .