# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units' in CNN

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, typeerror

I am trying to build a CNN for MNIST fashion, But not sure what is the issue here. I am getting thbis type error..

I have use Seuqential network,but MAxpooling and FLattena dn dense layers. But issue is in DEnse layer

```
model = Sequential() # type of DNN
model.add(Convolution2D(28, 3, 3, input_shape = (28, 28, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 100, activation="relu"))   ##### 128 nodes in this layer
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-90929a8a33e8> in <module>
  3 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  4 model.add(Flatten())
 ----> 5 model.add(Dense(output_dim = 100,kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation="relu"))   

  6 model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))




 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) function definition of Dense is as such,

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units,
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
    bias_initializer="zeros",
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    **kwargs
)
```

`units` is not an optional parameter.
You seem to forget writing unit argument on first Dense call

Comment: would you be kind enough to look through a particular question...I am sitting for a day with model...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720811/how-to-build-a-cnn-model-for-mnist-fashion-and-test-it-with-a-another-set-of-ima

Answer (score 1):

Seems like, here's the solution, [TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: "units"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840525/typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-units), you passing wrong arguments:

```
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 100, activation="relu"))
```

instead of:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation='relu'))   
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I've just checked the library, and there units like required positional argument:

```
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units,
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
    bias_initializer="zeros",
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    **kwargs
)
```

Comment: Yep. Looks like this to be the case. In the code shared in the line after `model.add(Flatten())` in the `Dense` function he hasn't mentioned the units. I think instead of unit's he has mistakenly used `output_dim`

Comment: I have an another query... How many layers are there in total in the above model

Comment: @ vova would you be kind enough to answer this particular question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720811/how-to-build-a-cnn-model-for-mnist-fashion-and-test-it-with-a-another-set-of-ima